# Brake caliper leak while pushing piston back

Tags: brake-calipers, brake-fluid, disk-brakes

I'm a bit worried about my front brake calipers on my MX5 MK1. I was replacing the front brake pads, and I had to push the caliper piston back in order to fit with the new pads. I used a C clamp to gently push the piston back, but after a few mm going back, it started leaking fluid.

Additionally, when I removed one of the pads, it was worn unequally, from left to right. Thinking about this, I remember that when I installed the old pads a few years ago, one of the calipers was struggling to get in, and the piston was grinding a bit on the back of the pad as I was pushing the caliper to close.

Is this an indication of a failing caliper or I should not worry and it is quite normal?

Thank you...

Comment: Was the piston damaged / rusty before you pushed it back in? If so then you may have damaged the seal - replace it.

Comment: @SolarMike the piston had some faint traces of rust, but nothing major.

Comment: Your “faint traces” can be enough to damage the seal...

Comment: Rebuild or replace the caliper.

Comment: Thank you guys for your replies, I will rebuild the caliper and let you know. Btw, I added a few details that just came to my memory, about what may caused all this. The caliper in question was a new replacement a few months ago.

Comment: I always open the bleed nipples before I push the pistons back, and discard the fluid that exits

Comment: @CaiusJard that's a good advice mate, I will have it in mind for the next time... Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your caliper has any brake fluid coming out of it, it's time to rebuild/replace the caliper. There should be absolutely no fluid loss anywhere in your braking system. If it is leaking at the caliper, not only is the caliper failing, but if the brake fluid gets on the rotor/pads, it won't provide much in the way of stopping, either. This is a huge safety risk for not only you, but anyone who might be riding in your vehicle, and anyone who might be in the way of the vehicle you are unable to stop in time to prevent an accident. Just as @Moab states in the comments, rebuild or replace the caliper. If it's leaking, it's not good.

Answer (score 1):

The brake calipers is a simple hydraulic pistons system, with the rubber rings. Replace the rubber seals it will do your job. Also check for any leaks from bleeder screws.